# node install atob globally

Tags: node.js, npm

I am having trouble using npm packages globally with node. (on Mac)

This is probably a very simple problem.

This seems to work if I install npm packages locally, but not globally.

I have this code (nt.js):

```
atob = require ('atob');
```

and have installed atob as:

```
npm install -g atob
```

but, when I try to run the code

```
$ node nt.js
node nt.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'atob'
Require stack:
...
```

Npm shows that atob is installed globally:

```
$ npm list -g
npm list -g
/usr/local/lib
├── atob@2.1.2
├── npm@7.5.4
├── ohm-js@16.0.0
├── pako@2.0.4
└── pegjs@0.10.0
```

$

Comment: do any of your other global npm packages work?

Comment: No, none of my global npm packages work.  I've had to install them locally for each project.  [I wonder if it's something as simple as using sudo?]

Comment: sounds like you need to fix your `$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

I looked on the npm website and they basically say that:
"Tip: If you are using npm 5.2 or higher, we recommend using npx to run packages globally."

try this => npx install -g atob

Comment: I don't think `npx install` works... it'd be just `npx atob ...`
`npx` is for executing, not managing packages